# Версионность и история изменений

Tags: python, diff

Имеется запись вида:

```
data = {'title': 'Заголовок',
    'text': 'Тело текста'}
```

Запись в единственном единственном экземпляре. Но необходимо организовать хранение истории изменений (подобие diff) НЕ В БАЗЕ. Прошу подсказать варианты хранения такой истории, а также возможность просмотра изменений и версий (git и другие готовые отдельные системы контроля версий прошу не предлагать). Желательно со ссылками и/или кодами Python.

Делаю первый раз, поэтому даже в виде идеи не совсем представляю как оно должно выглядеть. Иначе бы сделал. Как раз и прошу варианты реализации подсказать. Кто как предполагает решить такую задачу?

Comment: *git и другие... не предлагать* - а почему? вы хотите систему контроля версий, но при этом не хотите, чтобы ее вам предлагали. Т.е. все-таки вам нужна какая-то система контроля, но git и прочее по какой-то причине не подходят. Может быть напишите эту причину? Тогда будет ясно, что либо это не причина и git вам подходит, либо будет ясно какой конкретно инструмент вам подойдет, а какой даже предлагать не имеет смысла

Comment: Странный вопрос, либо неполный, либо некорректный. Если вам нужен костыль, напишите его. Простейший вариант - используйте ту же консольную утилиту `diff` и пишите ею в файл с изменениями. В общем, наваяйте свой скрипт, если не хотите использовать готовые решения.

Comment: Планируется держать многочисленные данных в иерархической структуре каталогов. git не подходит потому, что в историю необходимо будет держать в каждом каталоге. git в каждом каталоге будет содержать много лишних файлов, что скажется на производительности.

Comment: Делаю первый раз, поэтому даже в виде идеи не совсем представляю как оно должно выглядеть. Иначе бы сделал. Как раз и прошу варианты реализации подсказать. Кто как предполагает решить такую задачу?

Comment: Не в базе? А где тогда? В памяти? Тогда персистентные структуры для вас. Что вы хотите в итоге получить?

Comment: Я не вижу причин не использовать БД, но если не хотите готовое решение, используйте свой велосипед с плоским файлом. Хотя это ничем не будет отличаться от использования той же SQLite, ну разве скорость работы чуточку повысите. В общем [модуль Shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) вам в помощь.

Comment: Я предполагаю примерно так:001/234/567/data/history чтоб можно было сравнить две версии и сделать откат при необходимости.

Comment: Ваши представления о производительности Git довольно-таки ошибочны. Он не держит лишних файлов в каждом каталоге.

Comment: `Запись в единственном единственном экземпляре` противоречит `Планируется держать многочисленные данных в иерархической структуре каталогов`. Так у вас одна запись или много?

Comment: На текущий момент сама запись без версий.

Comment: На текущий момент сама запись без версий. Многочисленные данные - многочисленные записи, но не имеющие одинаковой структуры. git и другие системы контроля версий не беру потому, данных (возможно) будет много и вытащить конкретную запись даже годичной давности будет весьма растратно как в плане производительности, так и по другим соображениям (в том числе и по ограничениям на inode)

Answer (score 1):

Самое тупое решение - это на каждое изменение сохранять версию зависимую от даты, например

/year/day/month/hour/min/sec/timestamp/rev_number(на всякий случай)/data.json

либо вообще это всё к файлу придёргивать.

Хранить именно дифф не советую, т.к. свой велосипед будет больно бить педалями по носу, прежде чем нормально поедет.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты реализации вы можете подсмотреть в уже реализованных опенсорсных системах контроля версий.

Если вам кажется, что `git` для вас слишком крут, посмотрите на остальные:

[Comparison of version control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software)

Вы уверены, что ни одна из них вам не подходит и вам так уж необходимо изобретать велосипед? Что из списка выше вы вообще щупали руками, не считая `git`?

Прежде чем бросаться с головой в велосипедостроение, нужно провести исследование существующих решений, сравнить их сильные и слабые стороны для конкретной задачи, хорошенько подумать и, возможно, согласиться на некоторый компромисс.

Прочитайте например, вот про эту систему: [Revision Control System](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System)

> Для каждого файла, зарегистрированного в системе, она хранит полную историю изменений, причём для текстовых файлов используется эффективный алгоритм дельта-компрессии, когда хранится только последняя версия и все межверсионные изменения.

Не это ли вы хотите получить? А система была написана ещё в 1985 году.

Comment: Подозреваю, что автор и Git не щупал. )

Comment: Уважаемый Nick Volynkin - не подозревайте за других!